# Good dataset for sentiment Analysis in Tickets for IT Support

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data, rnn, lstm

I am working on Sentiment Analysis in Tickets for IT Support, But I have only seen the movie reviews and Twitter sentiment analysis which are not related to my work. I found a research paper related to my research work on this link  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7832903/  but they have denied giving the datasets. For my model, It gives 89% accuracy for the IMDB datasets but for IT purpose It doesn't.

Can anybody suggest some other datasets which can help me to increase the result?

Comment: How about training you own dataset? Have you explored that avenue?